# Deleting child object which refers its parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Suppose the following classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Int32 Id
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public virtual IList<Child> Children
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public Int32 Id
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [Required]
    public virtual Parent Owner
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

I'm facing problems when trying to delete some Child record this way:

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    var DummyInstance = new Child { Id = 1 };

    db.Set<Child>().Attach(DummyInstance);
    db.Set<Child>().Remove(DummyInstance);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

It throws a **DbUpdateException** as following:

> Entities in 'Context.Children' participate in the 'Child_Owner' relationship.
>   0 related 'Child_Owner_Target' were found.
>   1 'Child_Owner_Target' is expected.

My intend is to avoid querying the object which will be deleted, and I'm only able to achieve that if I assign a dummy instance of its parent object too:

```
var DummyInstance = new Child { Id = 1, Owner = new Parent { Id = 1 } };
```

However, the parent Id is not always known (moreover, it does not seem a suitable approach). Is there a way to let EF to perform this operation avoiding unnecessary queries?

Comment: Are you giving us all the code? The `Child_Solution` looks like some other relation than Parent-Child.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace that reference. I do map my original entities with Fluent API, and this is just a shortened version: using that [Required] attribute over Owner property I still get the same behavior.